# cauchy shwarz inequality using inner product form

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I'm trying to prove the cauchy schwarz inequality $$<x,y>\ \leq \ ||x||||y||$$

by letting $c=\dfrac{1}{||x||}$ and $d=\dfrac{1}{||y||}$, then using the fact that $||cx\pm dy||\geq 0$.  I began by substituting in for $c$ and $d$ then writing 
$$\bigg|\bigg|\dfrac{x||y|| \pm y||x||}{||x||||y||}\bigg|\bigg|\geq0$$ where I then continued by bringing the denominator to the other side

$$\bigg|\bigg|x||y||\pm y||x||\bigg|\bigg|\geq ||x||||y||$$

How can I proceed?  assuming I took the right first steps.  To get the inner product I suspect I'm to rewrite the two norms on the left side as a tuples and cancelling terms until I get $x_1y_1+...+x_ny_n$

also, I began with this method because it's a hint provided by munkres in his text analysis on manifolds.  so for the hint $||cx\pm dy||\geq 0$ I should most likely choose $+$ or $-$, whichever allows me to get the desired inequality

Comment: Somewhere you will need to use the inner product, and not just the norm. You could write that first inequality as $\langle cx + dy, cx + dy \rangle \geq 0$, and start expanding using properties of the inner product, like linearity.

Comment: Please, if you are ok, you can accept the answer and set it as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

maybe the hint was given in order to consider $$<\frac {x}{||x||},\frac{y}{||y||}> \ = \ <a,b> \ = \sum a_ib_i \ \leq \ 1$$

and then using the fact that $$a_i b_i \leq \frac {1}{2}(a_i^2+b_i^2)$$ and $$\sum a_i^2 = \sum b_i^2\ = \ 1$$